# Getting errors while creating trigger function from .sql file in postgres

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I'm trying to inject .sql file like xyz.sql in that I have created some triggers and in another file I'm implementing this function but I'm getting these errors in.

Maybe I am missing syntax, because the same is running in PostgreSQL editor but I have to write in .sql file, please check this combined image

[image]

Comment: Show us the Java code that runs those scripts - **[Edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Okay I will not write next time,

Answer (score 0):

On the create trigger section, the ending semi-colon is missing.

PS: in the future, please copy-paste the code and error, not a screenshot of it

Comment: Even though after adding semicolon it is showing same error.